# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; Timestamp table

Tags: mysql

I've searched the page for answers, however, I am not able to solve this.

I receive the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

When I am pasting this in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Votes_History` (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Coin varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

This is what I used to enter data into the `Votes_History` table:

```
INSERT INTO `Votes_History` (`ID`, `Username`, `Coin`, `Timestamp`) 
VALUES
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Robin

Comment: Your create table statement [appears to be working fine](http://rextester.com/CYFJB81812).  Maybe you can show us the full `INSERT` you tried to do which caused this error?

Comment: The full <code>INSERT</code> is: <code>INSERT INTO `Votes_History` (`ID`, `Username`, `Coin`, `Timestamp`) VALUES</code>

Comment: If that's really what your ran, the reason for the error is...you never specified any values to insert.

Comment: I think you've created your columns without ' and in the insert you are using ' in the columns names

Answer (score 0):

If the query you are using is the same as the one in this sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01dcb/1 then you query is valid

What I remarked is you are declaring `Timestamp` as `int(11)`, if you give to your `INSERT` statement `Timestamp` value as `NOW()` or `DATE()` then its a syntax error.

For `TIMESTAMP` type example:

```
# This table used TIMESTAMP type
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Votes_History_Timestamp` (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Coin varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

INSERT INTO `Votes_History_Timestamp` (`Username`, `Coin`, `Timestamp`) 
VALUES ('Hamza', '50MAD', NOW());
```

SQLFiddle link for timestamp : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7878c9/1